# Looking for a way to list video length in nautilus list view column

Tags: nautilus, video, filesystem, files

I'm looking for a way to list the video length in the nautilus list view column along with the size/type/modified columns. Any easy way to do this?

[Nautilus List View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXZUo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can install this package to get more column options:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-columns
```

The attribute you are looking for is `Length`.

Comment: For some reason when I add the repository the nautilus-columns package is listed, but it says it can't find it even after rebooting and removing and re-adding the repository.